# PHP site map + htaccess cut links

Tags: php, .htaccess, sitemap

i'm trying to make a site map and i have a question: my htaccess file cut my links from http://example.com/index.php?page=10 to http://example.com/index/page/10/ the question is what type of links i must mention in sitemap.xml (with .php and ?attribute=parameter or index/page/  ect...) and does it matter at all?

Thanks.

By the way one more question, better make site map in php and than save file in .xml or there is another way for make map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the links that don't cause a redirect. That is likely /index/page/10/ but it really depends on your setup. If you go to index.php?page=10 and it changes the url to /index/page/10/ then you want to use /index/page/10/ and vise versa. If neither of them perform a redirect then you need to fix your htaccess to canonicalize them or use canonical tags in your pages.